# Is there a way to retrieve Facebook APP credentials using Facebook App id and Facebook App secret?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have created an facebook app long time ago and integrated it with salesforce through Oauth , using App id and App secret provided by facebook app.
Now,I have lost my Facebook app credentials but have App Id and App Secret. So is there any way to retrieve my facebook app login credentials using AppId and App Secret. I dont even remember the email Id or App name, I used to create that Facebook App.

Comment: Unclear what you mean by “Facebook app login credentials”? Do you mean the credentials of the _FB account_ you used to set this app up? Well, that should have been done through your personal account anyway – you are not allowed to set up fake accounts for this purpose.

Comment: If your app was set to public, then you can simply use the Graph API Explorer to find the app name at least – simply request the details for the app id.

Comment: Well, if getting the (available) app details via API doesn’t help you (granted, it probably won’t), then you might simply have to create a new app, and use that from now on.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. There are no credentials for Facebook apps, they are linked to your personal account (or now business). So going to [/apps](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) should list all your apps. If you created a fake account and created the app using that, they you should try to remember your account details (at least email), login (if the account is not yet disabled) and change the admin to your personal one.